# How can I get the size of each sub-directory of a remote computer using credentials with powershell?

Tags: powershell, size, powershell-3.0, filesize

I'm looking to get all of the sizes of all directories for a given computer and drive.  However, I need to be able to include credentials.

```
$dirSize = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -force | select Length  |Measure-Object -Sum length
```

This is what I want it to do, but I cannot use credentials with get-childitem

Answer (score 0):

You should look into enabling PowerShell Remoting, either through Active Directory Group Policy, or using the `Enable-PSRemoting` (from an Administrator PowerShell prompt). You will need to enable PowerShell Remoting on both the host **and** target systems.

Once Remoting has been configured, you can specify credentials using the `-Credential` parameter on the `Invoke-Command` PowerShell command.

Since the `Get-ChildItem` command will be running in the local context (on the remote computer) at that point, you won't need to worry about specifying additional credentials to that particular command.